# Why Unable to use Date Null check in an Entiltement Process?

Tags: apex, casemilestone, entitlements

I am trying to create an `Entitlement Process` to use the `Apex class`. In that Class, Once Deadline Value is populated (it will be future date), then `TimeCalculator` class will calculate the difference between `Deadline Date` and `Current Date` facing the below error and set that value in to the Targer Time.

Deadline is Date and when I am checking its not null. I see the below error. Please guide.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with entitlement processes, but if it works like views than you can just leave the value empty and it will find null values. Have you perhaps tried that?

Comment: @Kasper You really should have added that as an answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox, As you wish. I really wasn't sure if that would work, but coming from you I assume it's the right answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem. You just need to leave the value empty. Dont put NULL value. It works fine.

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if it has solved your problem. That way future visitors to this sight can easily see what worked and what hasn't.

Comment: I can't accept answers for you ;). However, i don't think there is a wait period for accepting answers. I think there should be a check mark you can click next to the up/down vote buttons. It may have to do with the fact that you are marking your own question as solved though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with entitlement processes, but if it works like views than you can just leave the value empty and it will find null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula evaluates to true option.
[image]

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(CustomField1, "close"),
    ISPICKVAL(CustomField2, "close"),
    NOT(ISNULL(Subject)),
    NOT(IsClosed) 
  )
```